# Passing parameter and value in Presto JDBC Connection Url

Tags: jdbc, presto, presto-jdbc

Passing parameter and value in Presto JDBC Connection Url. For example i would like to pass a custom parameter "abc" with value "1234567890". 
Would the below jdbc connection url works with the above requirement? 
**jdbc:presto://example.net:8080/hive/sales?abc="1234567890"**

Comment: How the value is used in Presto server? Could you share the final goal?

Comment: Do you want something like "extra credentials"?

Answer (score 1):

Presto JDBC does not support arbitrary parameters in JDBC connection URL.

The available parameters are documented here:
https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html#parameter-reference

If you want to pass some kind of a token to be consumed by a Presto connector, you can use `extraCredentials` parameter.